# solve trigonometric equation $\cos(2x) + \cos\left(x\right) -2 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Hi I can't figure out  how to solve this equation:
$$\cos\left(2x\right) + \cos\left(x\right) - 2 = 0$$

I think I'm supposed to rewrite $\cos\left(2x\right)$ into something else and then go from there. I tried a bunch of rewrites but nothing seems to get me anywhere unfortunately.

edit--

due to recommendation here I did an substitution for $u=\cos\left(x\right)$ But now I'm stuck again. Here's what I did

$2u + u -3 = 0$

$2u/2 + u/2 -3/2 = 0$

Here I used the Reduced quadratic equation to obtain the result $u1 = 1, u2 = -3/2$

Comment: Hint: $\lvert \cos x\rvert \leqslant 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Take a look and see if it helps you get unstuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the identity $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1,$$ and make the substitution $u=\cos x.$ What sort of equation do you get?

As a side note, this approach has the benefit of generality, since there's no need to assume that $x$ is real (though I'm sure you're working in the reals). The simplest path, though, assuming that you *are* working with the reals, is to take the hint that Daniel and Boris recommend.

---

**Added**: You seem to have noticed that the substitution gets you a quadratic equation (though it doesn't look like it, based on your formatting). Namely, we get $$2u^2+u-3=0,$$ so $u=1$ or $u=-\frac32,$ as you saw. In context, this means that we have $\cos x=1$ or $\cos x=-\frac32.$ Since (I assume) we're dealing with real values of $x,$ then $\cos x=-\frac32$ is not possible (as Daniel and Boris pointed out). Hence, $\cos x=1.$ For what values of $x$ is this true?

Answer (score 9):

Since $|\cos t|\le 1$, we have $\cos x=\cos 2x =1$ etc.